# How to mute audio in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I have created `AVAudioPlayer`, Now I want to mute it when user click button.

Here what I have tried :

```
player.volume = 1.0  //when first time i initiate my player


- (IBAction)speakerOnOff:(id)sender {
    if (player.volume == 1.0) {

        [player setVolume: 0.0];

        NSLog(@"1volume is:%f",player.volume);
    }else if (player.volume == 0.0) {

        [player setVolume: 1.0];

        NSLog(@"2volume is:%f",player.volume);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`if (player.volume = 1.0)` and `if (player.volume = 0.0)` are erroneous at least on two levels. First, C is not Pascal - the `=` operator is an assignment, probably you meant `if (player.volume == 1.0)` instead.

Two, even this wouldn't be any good - comparing floating-point numbers [does not do what you think it does](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf). You better set a Boolean flag to indicate the state of the player (and omit the `else if` part since it's redundant):

```
- (IBAction)speakerOnOff:(id)sender
{
    static BOOL muted = NO;
    if (muted) {
        [player setVolume:1.0];
    } else {
        [player setVolume:0.0];
    }
    muted = !muted;
}
```

Comment: ahh,silly me,thank for the ans and comment.i want to kill my self

Comment: from the code above, isn't muted always equals to No?

Answer (score 1):

swift 2+ solution

```
    let musicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var IsMuted:Bool = false

    if IsMuted == false {
      IsMuted = true
      musicPlayer.volume = 0
    } else {
      IsMuted = false
      musicPlayer.volume = 1
    }
```

-> Don't forget to `setCategory` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`

```
do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
      return print("couldn't set session")
    }
```