# AVAudioPlayer setVolume - How?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Does anyone know the best way to mute game sounds on my app.

I am currently using SystemSoundID which I know cannot have the volume adjusted and need to move to AVAudioPlayer.

Ideally I need a settings page where the volume can be changed and the volume level saved so when coming back out or leaving and re-opening the app it remembers to volume level?

I have tried it various ways using AVAudioPlayer but had no success at present and am receiving some bad reviews for my app for people saying they hate that they cant control the game volume... HELP!!

Answer (score 6):

for AVAudioPlayer you can use this code to mute volume

in .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    BOOL muted;
}
```

and in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    muted = NO;
}

- (IBAction)speakerOnOff:(id)sender
{

    if (muted) {
        muted = NO;
        [player setVolume:1.0];
    } else {
        muted = YES;
        [player setVolume:0.0];
    }
}
```

this code is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880443/how-to-mute-audio-in-avaudioplayer) great answer.

Comment: I've tried this before. But it seemed to not remember it, so each time It loaded a different ViewController it would ignore the it and just play it at full volume?

Comment: check my answer now ,now your vc will remember the value of muted and do changes acordiglly.

Comment: is there a better way to do it so I could use volume sliders instead so they can have the volume at the level they want?

Comment: I assume this will work on all VC's. So if they mute it on the main page all other VC will know what the volume level is?

Comment: It only remembers the muted option on the one VC. All the other VC's still play the sound

Comment: yes they will,coz we here saving our muted variable for this vc. to use it in centrally you have to use some method to pass that variable around the vc.

Comment: AVAduioPlayer play pause should be a singleton class that way u dont have to take tension of VC's