# iOS - Is it possible to mute/unmute audio(microphone record) while recording video using AVFoundation in swift? Then Save in library

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, video-recording

Is it possible to mute/unmute audio(microphone record) while recording video using AVFoundation in swift? Then the recorded video should save in the library. I am using below the third party code https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager.

Comment: `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)` ? found https://stackoverflow.com/a/34980966/4601900